# Can two different labels on a Neo4j cypher be the same?

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

Say I have a graph with people who can know each other and do crime. Now I want to get all the criminals who know each other. So I do something like this:

```
MATCH (c:Crime)<-[:PARTY_TO]-(p1:Person)<-[:KNOWS]-(p2:Person)-[:PARTY_TO]->(c2:Crime)
```

Now the question is: does this cypher return two different persons who have commited the same crime?

I know that if I did:

```
MATCH (c:Crime)<-[:PARTY_TO]-(p1:Person)<-[:KNOWS]-(p2:Person)-[:PARTY_TO]->(c:Crime)
```

Then they would have commited the same crime, but if the two crimes have a different label, can they be the same?

Answer (score 0):

You use the same label :Crime so it is the same crime. If the crime has another label and you use it on your query then it should be fine.

> For example; you have a name and a nickname; if your friend calls you
> by your nickname (another label); then you are still the same person
> when another person calls you by your real name.

Nodes can be labelled more than once (like :Crime and :Robbery) but it is referring to the same node.